# How to access `req` object in Nuxt3 Route Middleware?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I want to access the req object in Nuxt3 Route Middleware just as we get in Nuxt2 middleware.

Here's the code:

**Nuxt2**

```js
// middleware/auth.js
export default ({ store, req }) => {
  if (req) {
    store.dispatch('auth/initAuth', { req })
  }
}
```

**Nuxt3**

```js
// middleware/auth.ts
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  if (to.params.id === '1') {
    return abortNavigation()
  }
  return navigateTo('/')
})
```

How I get this `req` object in Nuxt 3 Middleware because as far as I know I think in Nuxt3 Route Middleware we only get `to` and `from` params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create server middleware in `/server/middleware` and use `defineEventHandler` handler:

```
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  console.log('New request: ' + event.node.req.url)
})
```

Here you find more info: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server

**Update:**

The `req` object in Nuxt2 is available only on server-side, when directly accessing the app or refreshing the page. If you go to any page on the client-side when navigating to further routes, the `req` object is `undefined`. This is normal behavior because `req` object is returned by Node.js, so this can only happen when Node.js generates page (when you navigating through routes, page is generated by the browser, so `req` object is not available).

The same situation is Nuxt 3, but in this version, you have split this to `/middlewares` and `/server/middlewares`.

Below, is a link to a simple Nuxt 3 app on StackBlitz, where can you try it. Notice how you open the app or refresh it in the browser, server middleware is executed, but when you navigate through routes it isn’t.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-7b634c?file=server%2Fmiddleware%2Ftest.js

Comment: let's say i want to run my middleware for /auth route. Does server middleware execute for /auth route and If yes then please let me know how.

Comment: As far as I know the server middleware only work for serve routes

Comment: Yes, middleware will be executed for `/auth` route. I updated my answer with more detailed explanation.

Comment: You can also retrieve it from the `nuxtApp` with `const { req, res } = useNuxtApp().ssrContext?.event.node`.